# Change data from columns to nested list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, text-editing

I need to move data from this format:

```
node 1   node 12 node 121
node 1   node 12 node 122
node 1   node 13
```

To this one:

```
node 1
   node 12
      node 121
      node 122
   node 13
```

Is there an easy way?

Note:

- Data is in Excel
- Target format may be Word
- There are up to 7 levels of depth
- They are hundreds of rows

Comment: This seems like a good code golf example for scripting languages :) Can you maybe run Python, Ruby or Perl scripts?

Comment: Hi @slhck, yes, I'm developer, I can write code in 15'. But I would like to find steps that a user can reproduce it. Thanks about language improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, try moving your data from the 3 columns shown into just one column, stacking one on top of the other.  Next, remove duplicates (on the Ribbon, choose "Data", "Remove duplicates").  Finally, sort in ascending order.